# c# - ForEach Memo Lines

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I am using XtraReport and a memo . I want to make rum loop for each memo and add to XtraReport .

My code:

```
foreach (string line in memo_autores.Text.Split('\n'))
            {
                    report.xrRichText1.Text = line;
            }
```

Out:

Only Last line of memo_autores

How can I do to fix this?

Comment: Why are you splitting on \n before adding to xrRichText1.Text?

Comment: Rum loop sounds like a good time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to concatenate instead of replacing the text altogether. Each iteration of the loop represents one line of text, so when you just assign inside the loop, you end up seeing the last line because that was the last value set. If you build up a string like below, then you will see all the text:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string line in memo_autores.Text.Split(new [] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None))
{
    sb.AppendLine(line);
}
report.xrRichText1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

As pointed out in the comments, this could be a much more direct route for copying over the full text:

```
report.xrRichText1.Text = memo_autores.Text;
```

Or with the newlines stripped out:

```
report.xrRichText1.Text = memo_autores.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
```

Comment: Well splitting on \n and then appending together gets him right back to memo_autores.Text, with some \r potentially thrown in depending on what was in Text to begin with.

Comment: That's a good point, I was assuming he wanted everything. There's definitely a more direct route if he wants to translate from the memo to report.

Comment: I think we need to know why he's splitting on \n to begin with in order to provide a good answer. Could be for example that he has "line1\nline2" and needs "line1\r\nline2" (in which case your answer would work), or it could be a different reason entirely.

Comment: Works Like a charm... really thanks. I understand the functioning of stringbuilder. But make a change at foreach (string line in memo_autores.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine)) for foreach (string line in memo_autores.Text.Split('\n')). Your code is Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Oops... I updated to use Environment.NewLine to handle the \r as well as \n and didn't get the string overload right. Fixed!